# Is it possible to modify this script to count characters up from zero?

Tags: javascript

I posted a similar question earlier, and I am sorry to ask again, I think perhaps I confused by over complicating it. I have this script for a character counter:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("output");
txt.setAttribute("maxlength", 60)
var maxLength = 60;
var demo = document.getElementById("count");
var checkLength = function(){
if(txt.value.length <= maxLength) {
    var result = demo.innerHTML =  " " + (maxLength-txt.value.length) 
};  
};
setInterval(checkLength, 300);
```

All I need it to change it so instead of starting at "50" as it does now, and counting down to "0", I want it to start at zero, and count up, no need for a max character output. I have tried to figure out modifying this myself, but nothing I have tried has worked. Please just answer with JavaScript, no jQuery.

Comment: it shows the difference of what you type and 60, doesn't count from 50

Comment: Change `var result = demo.innerHTML =  " " + (maxLength-txt.value.length) ` line to `var result = demo.innerHTML =  " " + (txt.value.length)` for it to count.

Comment: @Dellirium Thank you, I really appreciate that, it's literally all I needed, I am using this script specifically because it seems to actually work on my form which pulls text entered to multiple sources and outputs to a single textarea, and this script actually updates the character count when combine all the forms in to one. I can't thank you enough. If you wanna post your answer as an answer to this question, I will be happy to mark it as accepted :) Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

Change

```
var result = demo.innerHTML = " " + (maxLength-txt.value.length)
```

line to

```
var result = demo.innerHTML = " " + (txt.value.length)
```

for it to count.